# MacBook Pro 15" Retina Display (Late 2013) - repeated display and vertical striping

Tags: macbook-pro, display, graphics, gpu

The last time I used my laptop was this past Friday night. My machine was working fine then. I shut it down, as I almost always do (rather than putting it to sleep), and didn't open it again until this morning.

[image]

The first screen was grayscale, looking like my login screen was being unsuccessfully repeated time and time again, and the black screen with many Apples upon my attempt to restart. The symphonic "dunnnnn" that happens when you turn on a MacBook was there, I could SEE my background, and see that it was responding to keyboard input. That's as far as I got with it before calling Apple support.

[image]

I spoke with a man named John who didn't seem too sure of what the problem was but DID say that there were some models that had issues and were part of a repair program. Mine was one model out of being covered, and I still don't know exactly what the issue is. Graphics card? Broken screen? Cursed by my enemies?

For reference, I keep my laptop in a padded gear bag with my camera gear. I've always handled it, never dropped it, never otherwise mistreated it in any way—

And then this. It's been a perfect machine otherwise and still runs like it did when I bought it new in October of 2014. I'm really freaking bummed and hoping that this can be solved. I will be going to an Apple Store in the city I'm moving to tomorrow.

Do I need a hardware repair or can I try software fixes?

Comment: First thing I would do is try [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.  Let us know what the results are.

Comment: Can't really see the screen, but I think I selected English and that it's diagnosing. Really not sure. If I could add a picture here, I would. Bah!

Comment: All right, I ran the diagnostic (again, I THINK). I couldn't see what it was trying to tell me.

Comment: If you can't see anything in Diagnostics, it's a hardware problem.  Try hooking it up to an external monitor to rule out the LCD or the GPU.

Comment: This is most probably a hardware failure of he GPU graphic system. MacBooks from 2011 until 2013 had problems with their graphic cards and a hardware replacement program us in place. Although you said yours was not covered, which might be true. I do not know how many generations were published in 2013. To my knowledge 2014 models were immune to the graphic problems ... try with an external monitor ... hardware repair could be around 750 euros. Good luck!